# A Key-Value pair containing Key-Value pair array as object c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to create an object which I want to serialize into a JSON file looking like:

```
"key": [
  {
    "id": "10000"
  }
],

    var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict2.Add("id", "10000");
    
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    dict.Add("key", dict2);
```

But it doesn`t work really.

Comment: `new { key = new[] { new { id = "10000" } } }`?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "But it doesn't work really"? What does it do, compared with what you want it to do? (Hint: your JSON contains an array. Your in-memory representation doesn't.)

Comment: Maybe next time try to use a converter which can help when serializing -> https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @gacaba3982: did any of this helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this code

```
    var values = new Dictionary<string, List<IdClass>> {
        {"key", new List<IdClass> { new IdClass{Id="10000"}}}
    };
    
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

output

```
{
  "key": [
    {
      "Id": "10000"
    }
  ]
}
```

class

```
public class IdClass
{
     public string Id {get; set;}
}
```